# how to recover deleted files in atom code editor

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, atom-editor, data-recovery

I have accidentally deleted a folder containing lots of important files using ATOM. when I deleted, it showed me move to trash and done. but when I go to trash I was empty even later I created a file and deleted it then I checked the trash folder it was still empty.

I am using **Ubuntu Linux 16**
please also suggest any folder recovery tool without mounting the disk.

thank you.

Comment: I think http://askubuntu.com/ is much better place to ask this question.

Comment: I have read lots of articles in askubunto.com but found nothing special

Comment: Ok, but this is not site about Ubuntu. Why did you ask here and not on https://askubuntu.com/? You question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Well, Stack overflow is having tags about ubuntu and atom so I posted it because I am getting a quicker response then askubunto.com

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Do you use ATOM for coding?

Answer (score 3):

Issue resolved. I used Find command in the root folder to search for my deleted files and I found them in different trash folder which was hidden

the folder where I found my files is

```
.Trash-1000/
```

Atom was actually moving files into a different folder it was not deleting.

so i hope this will help others to find out the files they deleted accidentally .

Answer (score 0):

I found the deleted files in the default trash folder of Ubuntu and just simply restored it from there.

Answer (score -1):

It's in the Recycle bin of your computer.